# Recurring articles one after the other

Tags: articles

Why is the word segway in the red box used with 'a' when is it repeated in the article and the headline of the article is used with 'the'?
[image]

Comment: "The" is used when talking about a specific thing so in the headline it is talking about a specific tour so it uses "the tour" (the type of tour is a Segway tour hence "the Segway tour") whereas "a" is used when talking in general terms, so "a Segway" is referencing the general item of "Segway" not any specific Segway. The second red box is talking about "Segway tours" in general not any specific one hence "a Segway tour."

Answer (score 1):

First thing to understand is that there are many Segways, but only one tour. You've heard of *The Tour de France*, right? It's a race, with lots of bicycles in it. Even though it is held every year, it's still *The* Tour.

The first mention you have highlighted is fine because it isn't referring to the tour of the headline. It refers to the vehicle itself, a Segway.

The second instance you highlighted could be seen as an inconsistency, or perhaps the writer is simply acknowledging that there are other tours of Budapest that can be done on Segways and *the* tour referred to in the headline is just the specific one that they participated in. Newspaper headlines don't necessarily strictly follow grammar, anyway, so most native speakers would not even notice this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

The first instance with the definite article in the title signals to the reader that the article will be about a specific tour in Budapest that will be described.

The second instance, with the indefinite article, backtracks the narrative and introduces a generic description that applies to all Segway tours on the planet and is not meant to describe this tour specifically.  This is meant as background.

The last instance is used as literary device to ground the reader in the type of tour being described.  It is a generic reference to set the stage for a more specific description.  It is a compact way of saying: "Among the many types of transportation you could take tour Budapest, if visitors take a Segway tour. they are taken....."  At that point, there is enough detail of the tour for the reader to recognize that these details describe the specific tour referenced in the title.

Comment: Thank you so much